# Bootstrap 3 grid works fine, at around 1170px all columns act like a col-lg-12 with a "display: block;" attribute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid

So, I'm creating this website and everything is perfect on a desktop. However, all hell breaks loose at around 1170px or so.

Basically, it doesn't matter which "col-lg-#" class I give the
, it just turns to 100% width and acts like a block element. For instance, I have three boxes up top with this class:

Content
Content
Content

All of them are inline-block elements. However, for some reason, at a certain resolution, these column width classes just seem to be completely ignored, as well as the inline or inline-block attribute. It just doesn't make any sense. I've used Bootstrap before and have never had this issue. But, right now, I cannot figure it out to save my life.

The only solution I can think of, is putting everything in an unordered list and adjusting the placement of everything with padding. However, that's just dumb and would take way too long.

Here are some screenshots of my issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/egy7c.jpg

I would add the code, but there's a lot of it. Not really sure what I should add.

Comment: Slim the program down to just what is needed to reproduce the issue and post that

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the class col-md-x as in the col-lg-x, remember, bootstrap grid give us 4 different classes of columns: xs, sm, md and LG for smartphones, tablets, desktop and larger devices , hope it was helpful